# How to add eventHandlers with local variables in a loop

Tags: javascript, scope, dom-events, pass-by-value

I'm sure I knew this at one point, but I've been away for a while and I can't figure it out anymore.

Let's say I have a collection of buttons ("Button A", "Button B", "Button C", represented by a NodeList retrieved by .getElementsByClassName("button").

I now want to add an EventHandler to these that makes use of some local variables passed by value at the time the handler is created. For a minimal example, let's use:

```
for (var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var inner = elems[i].innerHTML;
    elems[i].onclick = function(){window.alert("Clicked on "+inner+" which is element number "+i)};
}
```

The desired result here would be that, when clicking on Button B, I get

```
Clicked on Button B which is element number 1
```

However, all buttons yield

```
Clicked on Button A which is element number -1
```

I understand why this happens, but how would I need to change the code to achieve the former? In case this is relevant, in the final eventhandler the i will not be used by itself, but to reference elem[i] again, which is passed into the handler as an argument.

Comment: Any specific reason for a decrementing loop rather than an incrementing one?

Comment: Was considered best practice when the order doesn't matter to only check the array length once. Not sure if it still is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `let` to declare the variable. This will create a block scope for the variable and will retain the correct value trough out the loop:

```
for (let i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

**Demo:**

```js
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (let i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var inner = elems[i].innerHTML;
  elems[i].onclick = function(){window.alert("Clicked on "+inner+" which is element number "+i)};
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Button A</button>
<button type="button">Button B</button>
<button type="button">Button C</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I also didn't know this when I was more active in JS. Is let somewhat new?

Comment: @Tobl, you are most welcome and yes it is relatively new (ES6) feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
for (var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  (function(i) {
    var inner = elems[i].innerHTML;
    elems[i].onclick = function(){window.alert("Clicked on "+inner+" which is element number "+i)};
  })(i);
}

<button type="button" class="btn">Button A</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button B</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button C</button>
```